# Question about Shemot, locusts

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim, bo, plagues-makkos, yam-suf

I have a question that I've asked to multiple rabbis but that remains unanswered:

> Dear Rabbi:
>
> Question about Parasha. In [Exodus 10:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.10.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the locusts enter the Red Sea. What is the connection with the Egyptians who also drowned in it?
>
> Yours Sincerely,
>
> Jerry
>   Netherlands

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for this intriguing question!

Comment: Hi and welcome -- I looked at the verse and it says that the wind hurled them Yama suf which could be read simply as "towards the Reed Sea". While the English says "into" two of the Aramaic renderings have "to the Reed sea."

Answer (score 11):

Rabbi Yosef Deutsch in [*Let My Nation Go*](https://www.feldheim.com/let-my-nation-go.html), page 259, writes:

> The wind carried every single locust east to the sea so that not one locust remained in Egypt. The locusts would await the Egyptians by the sea, and when the Egyptians would pursue the Jewish people to the sea, the locusts would torment them once again.

The footnotes source this to the work *V’imrei No’am*, in its comments to Exodus 10:19, but I can’t seem to find a copy of this work online. Maybe someone else can take it from here.

Comment: There are 26+7 results on HebrewBooks for אמרי נועם or אמרי נעם, so maybe it's in one of them (if someone has the patience to sift through them all)

Comment: Here it is: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44618&st=&pgnum=24&hilite= `ויתקעהו ימה סוף - למה לשם יותר מבשאר מקומות? וי"ל לפיכף תוקעם שמה לפי שכשיבוא פרעה בים אז יבואו עליהם. וכן כל מכות שלקו המצריים לקו על הים` @ba I can't say I'd heard of it, but various editions of it account for 15% of the מלא hits!